# Change reviews tab on ultimo theme

Tags: php, magento

We use a third party for product reviews and would like to add their widget to the product tab in ultimo.

We know where the original file is, but how do we create a new file so it does not over ride the original magento files when we do an update?

frontend/base/default/template/reviews/product_reviews_widget.phtml is where new reviews widget is showing.

frontend/ultimo/default/template/review/product/view/list.phtml is current review tab on product page where we want the file above to show.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make a copy of the following file into your own theme directory:

```
app\design\frontend\ultimo\default\template\catalog\product\view\tabs.phtml
```

as such:

```
 app\design\frontend\ultimo\YOURTHEME\template\catalog\product\view\tabs.phtml
```

Then you can safely amend and add tabs as static blocks, widgets etc with the overwriting file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you just clarify, do I just create a new folder for the theme directory and call it what I like?

Comment: Correct, but you will need to assign that in the configuration (under Design) so that Magento looks first at your theme and then uses ultimo default as a fallback.